# What should I add to print all the questions I have passed in the driver class?

Tags: java, object, tostring

These are my quiz and question class.

```
class Question{
    String question, answer;
    Question()
    {
        question = null;
        answer = null;
    }
    
    public Question(String question, String answer)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return question;
    }
}

class Quiz extends Question{
    String name;
    
    Quiz(String name)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addQuestion(Question q)
    {
        answer = q.answer;
        question = q.question;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return name+"\n\n" + question;
    }
}
```

And this is my driver class.

```
public class QuizSample{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Quiz sample = new Quiz("Sample 1903 Quiz");
        
        sample.addQuestion(new Question("Who is known as the father of Java?", "James Gosling"));
        sample.addQuestion(new Question("Write a statement that assigns the length of a string s to int i", "i = s.length();"));
        sample.addQuestion(new Question("True or false: assigning an int to double is an example of a widening conversion", "true"));
        
        System.out.println(sample);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

> Sample 1903 Quiz
> True or false: assigning an int to double is an example of a widening conversion

**But I want to print all the questions that I have passed.**
Please help guys.

Comment: Your classes can't handle that, Whenever you use `addQuestion()` it will delete the older value stored in `sample`. try using a list to store the questions, and print it accordingly

Comment: Making `Quiz` as the extension class of `Question` does not solve the purpose. Rather, `Quiz` should contain list of `Question`

Comment: Here Quiz is not a Question rather it is a collection of questions. You need to refactor your code. You should use inheritance for `is a` relation. You may use an array of strings for storing that all the answers the user has provided. Then iterate over each question and check whether it is correct or wrong based on comparing it with the answer value from Quiz class and accordingly print the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Quiz` does not need to extend `Question` but rather to have a collection of questions (list or set).

Also, `toString` method needs to be updated to pretty print questions.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Quiz {
    String name;
    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Quiz(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addQuestion(Question q) {
        questions.add(q);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return name+"\n\n" + questions.stream()
                                      .map(Question::toString)
                                      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Quiz class can have a List to store all the questions,

like

```
List<Questions> lstQuestions = new ArrayList<Questions>();
```

and can be used in addQuestion method to add all the questions,

```
 public void addQuestion(Question q)
    {
        lstQuestions.add(q);
    }
```

and the main method can look like below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to my Quiz");
        
        for(Question quest : lstQuestion){
            System.out.println(quest);
            String ans = console.next();
            if(quest.getAnswer().equals(ans.trim())){
                System.out.println("right answer");
            }else{
                System.out.println("wrong answer");
            }
            
        }
        console.close();

    }
```